# Android app not compatible with HTC Desire S

Tags: android, compatibility, htc-android

I have built an app with minimum sdk 8 in android manifest.xml file. But it gives me the following error when i try to download it from Google play.
"This app is incompatible with your  HTC Desire.
This item is not compatible with your device."
My HTC model number is: HTC A8181.
Same for Galaxy Tab. GTP7500
Why is that so?

These are the following lines I have added in my manifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Your device is currently running Android 2.2? Do you have any other requirements in your Manifest, like screen resolution or specific features?

Comment: yes its currently running 2.2... and yes i have build it for galaxy tablet as well...which is for xlarge...and for landscap i have layout-land and xlarge-land. I have edited my question..please check it out. Thanks

Comment: Nothing in what you posted so far would make it incompatible, provided you upgraded the Desire from the Android 2.1 (API 7) it shipped with, like Asok said. Can you post your full manifest and the output of running the "aapt dump badging" command on the APK? aapt is in the platform tools directory under the sdk directory that can be downloaded from the SDK manager.